# Does variable caching will be applied if I create an instance of the class from different worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 workers and both workers are calling a factory who initialize the instance of a class and inside the initialize method I have used the variable caching so that both workers can take the advantage of variable caching while creating an instance of the class.

```
class BoxFolderDocumentSynchronizerJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(document_store_id, folder_id)
    synchronizer = DocumentSynchronizerFactory.get_synchronizer(document_store, folder_id)
  end
end

class DeleteBoxFolderDocumentJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(document_store_id, folder_id=nil)
    synchronizer = DocumentSynchronizerFactory.get_synchronizer(document_store, folder_id)
  end
end

module DocumentSynchronizers
  class Base
    attr_reader :document_store, :facility

    def initialize(document_store, folder_id=nil)
      if document_store
        @folder_id = folder_id
        @document_store  = document_store
        @facility = document_store.facility
        #Fetch all the document store(project) documents from S3/Box service provider
        @service_provider_documents_hash ||= DocumentStoreAdapterHandler.new(@document_store).list(folder_id)
        @vueops_documents_hashmap ||= @document_store.documents.inject({}){|hash, document| hash[document.file_id] = document; hash}
      else
        raise "Document store instance should not be nil"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My question is - when the variable caching scope ends?

Comment: Where is "get_synchronizer" method defined?

Comment: Using `@variable ||= ...` only makes sense if the line is executed multiple times, like for example in a getter method ([memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)). If the line is execute just once in the object's lifetime – like those in `initialize` – there's no difference to `@variable = ...`

Comment: @Pascal, a class method inside the class DocumentSynchronizerFactory.

Comment: @Stefan : good point, i added this to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two consecutive calls of the method could, depending on your setup, end up being executed in

- the same process in the same thread (memoization works)
- the same process in a different thread (memoization works)
- different processes (memoization does not work)
- even different machine/vm (memoization does not work)

If the workers use the **same instance** of DocumentSynchronizers, then caching will work, otherwise not.

In your case (expanding on the comment by @Stefan) the memoization doesn't bring any benefit because it is used inside the `initialize` method. This method is only executed **once** and **nothing** is executed **before** that could set a value. So there is no difference to `@variable = xxx`.

Memoization makes more sense if you use it like this:

```rb
class Something
  def value
    @value ||= some_expensive_calculation_that_can_be_cached
  end
end
```

and then do not use `@value` directly but use the method `value`. This has the added benefit of deferring the calculation until you actually use it (if, it is not always used)